# "pathMatch": "full" for empty-path route causes blank view

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have the following routes:

app-routing.module.ts:

```js
[
    ...
    {
        path: "",
        loadChildren: () => import("./tabs/tabs.module").then(m => m.TabsPageModule),
        // "pathMatch": "full",
    },
    {
        path: "**",
        redirectTo: "",
        "pathMatch": "full",
    },
]
```

tabs-routing.module.ts:

```js
[
    {
        path: "tabs",
        component: TabsPage,
        children: [
            {
                path: "products",
                loadChildren: () => import("../tab1/tab1.module").then(m => m.Tab1PageModule),
                "pathMatch": "full",
            },
            {
                path: "catalogue",
                loadChildren: () => import("../tab2/tab2.module").then(m => m.Tab2PageModule),
                "pathMatch": "full",
            },
            {
                path: "account",
                loadChildren: () => import("../tab3/tab3.module").then(m => m.Tab3PageModule),
                "pathMatch": "full",
            },
            {
                path: "",
                redirectTo: "products",
                "pathMatch": "full",
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        path: "",
        redirectTo: "tabs",
        "pathMatch": "full",
    },
]
```

The [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Route) for `Route.pathMatch` states:

> The path-match strategy 'full' matches against the entire URL. **It is important to do this when redirecting empty-path routes.** Otherwise, because an empty path is a prefix of any URL, the router would apply the redirect even when navigating to the redirect destination, creating an endless loop.

So that's what I've tried, adding `"pathMatch": "full",` to my `path: "",` in my app routing module (the line that is commented out in the snippet above). However, doing so breaks my app and I cannot figure out why.

Broken paths such as `localhost:8100/foo` correctly redirect me to `localhost:8100/tabs/products`, but the view is completely blank (an empty ion-router-outlet). No errors are logged in my browser console (or IDE's integrated terminal). My app so far is just a small edit of the `ionic start` tabs template and I have not touched any router outlets. Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In tabs-routing.module.ts:

```
[
{
    path: "tabs",
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
        {
            path: "products",
            loadChildren: () => import("../tab1/tab1.module").then(m => m.Tab1PageModule)
        },
        {
            path: "catalogue",
            loadChildren: () => import("../tab2/tab2.module").then(m => m.Tab2PageModule)
        },
        {
            path: "account",
            loadChildren: () => import("../tab3/tab3.module").then(m => m.Tab3PageModule)
        },
        {
            path: "",
            redirectTo: "products",
            "pathMatch": "full",
        },
    ],
},
{
    path: "",
    redirectTo: "tabs",
    "pathMatch": "full",
},
]
```

This will work for you

Comment: Hi, I have given that a try, uncommenting my `pathMatch` in app-routing and commenting those 3 `pathMatch`es in tabs-routing. However, I still face the same issue.